# JSON Download @ onCreateView leaves recyclerView empty

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, download, adapter

```
    if (isConnected()) {

        Event  eInstance = new Event();
        theEvents = eInstance.downloadEvents(eventsNightlife, getActivity());
        rAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(theEvents);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);
        progrsBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ....
```

This is part of the code that runs at "onCreateView". The method downloadEvents uses Volley to download JSON data, extract it and return a list of items (theEvents). Now when my app starts, the recycler view is empty. If I go to my home screen out of the app and then run my app again, this time the data sometimes gets downloaded.

**I debugged step by step, and at first launch (i mean when the app is not just resuming), theEvents is empty, so the download didn't return or manage to return anything...**

Suggestions on how to execute things before the UI has been shown to the user or what actually needs to be done to approach this task better?

Also, I use a swipeRefreshLayout and at its onRefresh method I do:

```
public void onRefresh() {
    Event  eInstance = new Event();
    theEvents = eInstance.downloadEvents(eventsNightlife, getActivity());

    rAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

but it doesn't work. I also tried to

```
rAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(theEvents);
    rAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.swapAdapter(rAdapter, false);
```

still not working.

**EDIT:** My downloadEvents method implementing Volley:

```
public List<Event> downloadEvents(String urlService, Context context) {
    eventsList = new ArrayList<>();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, urlService, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    try {
                        String durationStr = null;


                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject eventJson = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            String title = eventJson.getString("EventTitle");
                            String body = eventJson.getString("EventBody");
                            String date = eventJson.getString("EventDate");
                            String time = eventJson.getString("EventTime");
                            int duration = Integer.parseInt(eventJson.getString("EventDuration"));
                            if (duration > 60) {
                                durationStr = "Duration: " + duration / 60 + " h";
                            } else if (duration < 60) {
                                durationStr = "Duration: " + duration + " m";
                            }
                            String place = eventJson.getString("EventPlace");
                            String organ = eventJson.getString("Organization");

                            Event event = new Event(title, body, date, time, durationStr, place, organ);
                            eventsList.add(event);

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY ERROR", "" + error);

                }
            }
            );
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    return eventsList;
}
```

Comment: Post your downloadEvents method body please

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for your purpose that is a simple and truth way.
Here, i write an example for how to use `EventBus` with `volley`.
Consider that i want to download some data.

This is the class that my download methods is inside it (you can add more methods to it in the future):

Im used `volley` to download my data:

```
// Download methods is inside volley
public class MyDownloader{

    public static void downloadData(){
         DownloadDataEvent dlDataEvent=new DownloadDataEvent();
         List<String> myResult=new ArrayList<>();

             ...
             @Override
             public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                 super.onResponse(response);
                 if(respone!=null){
                     // Do what i want with my received data
                     dlDataEvent.setData(response);
                 }
                 // Post my event by EventBus
                 EventBus.getDefault().post(dlDataEvent);
              ...

         }
    }
}
```

This is my event:

```
public class DownloadDataEvent{
    private JSONArray mData;

    public void setData(JSONArray data){
         mData=data;
    }

    public JSONArray setData(){
        return mData;
    }

}
```

Now i want to use my downloadData() method inside my MainActivity:

(I called my downloadData method inside `onCreate`.)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ...

         // I have to register this class for EventBus subscriber:
         if(!EventBus.getDefault().isRegister(this)){
              EventBus.getDefault().registerSticky(this);
         }

         // Call my downloadData method
         if(isConnected()){
              MyDownloader.downloadData();
         }
     }

     // And for receive the data through EventBus, i have to create a 
     //   method (subscriber) in this template:
     public void onEventMainThread(DownloadDataEvent downloadDataEvent){
          JSONArray result=downloadDataEvent.getData();
          // Do what i want with my received data
     }
}
```

you can create more than one subscriber every where you want to use received data.

- I passed JSONArray to my DownloadDataEvent that it is not good. you can deserialize your received data and pass it to your DownloadDataEvent.
- I used Volley to download data
- Maybe my descriptions were confusing, but `EventBus` is a well-known library and is very easy to use.

Comment: So I read around and I didn't find much on EventBus. Almost no tutorials at all and I don't get how to use it. I am not that good in Android yet so I even got confused what part of your example was purely an example and what was part of EventBus. So, DownloadDataEvent is more elegantly put just the Event class where I make an Event object. I already have that one. Is Downloader the class where you suppose that I download my data with Volley? You just mean that after I normally download my data, I pass it as an object to the  EventBus.getDefault().post(dlDataEvent); ???

Comment: Could you expand a little bit on your answer please?

Comment: You can find a lot about EventBus in the web.
My answer has been changed. hope be helpful.
However im sorry if my answer is confusing.